# GPU PCIe lane usage

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, motherboard, gpu, pci-express

I have **Asus TUF Gaming RTX 3060ti**, **Asus Prime Z490-V** motherboard and **i7-10700F** CPU, GPU is installed on the top x16 slot on the motherboard. When checking nVidia panel in system information section, it says *PCIe x2 Gen3*, I also checked GPU-Z, it states the same, I tried putting load to the GPU but still stays the same *PCIe x2 instead of x16*, I also tried gaming to see if it changes but it doesn't. It runs okay but not sure if it is maximum performance I should be getting. I tried OctaneBench and the score is close to other 3060tis. Is it a software issue or should I be worried?
[image]
[image: motherboard manual]
Here is a screenshot from GPU-Z
[image: GPU-Z]
[image: GPU-Z 2]

Comment: By "top x16 slot" you definitely mean the slot closest to the CPU, right?

Comment: @Mokubai yes, it is the slot closest to the CPU

Comment: That sounds like something odd between your GPU and CPU, have you checked the slot and graphics card connectors are clean and clear, that your power supply is up to the job, and that it is all fitted correctly? Your motherboard manual definitely says it should be x16 in that slot. https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1200/PRIME_Z490-V/E16508_PRIME_Z490-V_UM_WEB.pdf.

Comment: So your performance is within a few points of your expected results.  Why would you be worried in a situation like that? What other PCIe (or NVMe) devices do you have installed in your system?

Comment: I added a picture, the locking is engaged. there is only 1 NVMe drive but it is connected to the chipset, other PCIe slots are not used

Comment: I can't find the specifications on the motherboard.  When the NVMe slot is used, that is being used, which PCIe slots are affected according to the manual?

Comment: @Ramhound NVMe uses chipset lanes, only top slot (where the GPU is connected) is connected directly to the CPU, other two NVMe slots and three PCIe slots are connected to the chipset

Comment: @JavokhirMatnazarov in this case yes, but on newer Intel motherboards and CPUs there is an extra 4 lanes on PCIe on the CPU which are generally wired up to an extra NVMe slot. 10th gen processors have 16 lanes that generally connect to the GPU PCIe slot, while 11th gen processors have 20 lanes, 16 for the GPU and 4 for the NVMe.

Comment: PCIe speed will mainly affect open world games that are constantly streaming texture and world data so depending on your game you may see *some* difference or you may see only a difference of a couple of seconds of loading time. For benchmarks which load up the GPU and set it going the score may well be nearly identical, but gaming may not be as good as it could be.

Comment: PCIe is mostly negotiated at the hardware level, though it can be restricted by configuration of the motherboard. Can you have a look in your BIOS and make sure that the slot has not been configured badly?

Comment: @Mokubai this PC is mainly used for work video editing and 3D animation in blender, could this affect the performance in this use case?

Comment: @Mokubai in BIOS didn't find anything wrong

Comment: PCIe gen 3 manages a little bit below 1GB/s per lane so x2 is just below 2GB/s instead of x16 being  15.75 GB/s (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express). If you can use 100% GPU decode and encode then the majority of the work will be on your GPU, and even if not you'll mostly be limited by your storage devices. For blender I wouldn't expect silly amounts of bandwidth either. It may take a second or two longer to set up scenes, but the performance after will be similar. This is the kind of thing that would annoy me, but chances are in the real world you won't notice much difference.

Comment: Out of curiosity can you get GPU-z https://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/ run up a benchmark and then post a screenshot of the GPUz window? I think GPUz includes a gpu loading tool.

Comment: @Mokubai I ran that before for 10 minutes, it still was x2. I don't have access to the PC right now but I can provide the screenshot later

Comment: @Mokubai I added GPU-Z screenshots, same story, running for 10 minutes, still reporting x2

Comment: https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/gpu-running-at-pcie-gen-3-x4-and-not-at-x16.3291231/#post-20145159 @JavokhirMatnazarov